# Boiling of liquids and their vapour pressure

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

Hello I was wondering about the boiling of liquids, I will use water as an example.

Liquids boil when their vapor pressure function p(T) exceeds the ambient pressure, for example water boils at 100 °C at 1 atm atmospheric pressure because at this pressure, its vapor pressure function p(T) has the value of 1 atm.

However, how is this atmospheric pressure defined? Is it just the gas pressure without the water vapor?

Suppose the water is heated up slowly until 100°C. It will form its own vapor, alongside the ambient pressure of 1 atm. So at the boiling point, does the water need to overcome the 1 atm ambient pressure + **its own vapor pressure** in the surrounding atmosphere to boil (would be over 1 atm tho) or just the pressure of the other gases?

Comment: It need not to be atmospheric pressure. Just pressure. It is hydrostatic pressure in the bulk liquid versus pressure of vapor. If the former is stronger, any microscopic bubble of vapor is smashed back to be liquid. If the latter is stronger, vapor pushes liquid away and bubbles grow.

Comment: Maybe think if you're using pressure cooker in this, or not?

Comment: Vapor is a gas like all others. Higher partial vapor pressure in air means lower partia pressure of permanent gases, maintaining locally the same total air pressure, unless balancing pressure is restricted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The water vapor partial pressure in the gas phase plus plus the partial pressures of oxygen, nitrogen, and trace species adds up to atmospheric pressure.

Comment: So it doesn’t matter if it is its own vapor or other gases, just sum it up and you get the pressure that needs to be overcome?

Comment: Yes, that’s right.

Comment: @Mäßige What made you think otherwise? A flying water molecule hits  water surface by the same way as any other gas molecule, participating on the total pressure.

Comment: I was just thinking that maybe because it is water vapor to the corresponding liquid phase, it somehow contributes to boiling point but that was wrong